# dynamic tree creation using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to create a dynamic tree using Jquery at client side and java(jsp/servlet) at backend using mysql database. Please suggest me how can I implement that. I want to add further functionality like add node,add child,add leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

[Treeview Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/). The documentation sais, that you basically just have to generate your List on the server side which will turn it into a tree view on the client side.